# How to manage lifetime of WPF application from Windows Service

Tags: wpf, windows-services

I am writing a prototype of software idea and what I need at this point is to ensure that WPF application after a crash will get restarted (in case it crashes).

I think of having a Windows Service which will check all running processes and if it won't find the WPF app (means it has crashed) it will start it. The Windows Service will also host a WCF service which will be consumed by the WPF.

So is it possible to find out which processes are currently running on the machine and start a WPF application from Windows Service?

There is a **good reason** for keeping the front-end alive all the time.

Comment: define "crash". Is it by application itself? Unhandled exceptions maybe? Or outside event? Termination from process manager?

Comment: It can be any, an OS signal, an internal exception or anything else. The idea is that this app will always execute (similar in some way to some antivirus applications).

Comment: What confuses me is fact, that you need something, that should run all the time, yet has UI. Normaly, theese kinds of scenario are handled by Windows service running the logic and separate application only as front-end to this service.

Comment: Yes, that is partially the case. I have both the service and the front-end which have to run all the time.

Comment: I won't go into many details, but this is only a concept, not a production code. I have to show how a software would work if it was a part of Windows OS, rather than independent application. In short there is a good reason why I want to make my app (front-end) run all time when the user is logged in.

Comment: >part of Windows OS
You probably dont know what "part of windows" mean. Did you ever see some windows application running constantly without ability to turn it off? I never saw such application. If it needs to run constantly, then it is a windows service.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11169/discussion-between-vitalij-and-euphoric)

Comment: What does this app do?   I don't even know of anti-virus that keep a UI element active.

Comment: I think Kaspersky antivirus does that. Again, I am not asking if this is a good thing to do, I am asking how to do it?

Comment: In the windows service have a thread that is constantly polling all running processes and if your UI process is not in that list then start it up from within the service.